# CS1002: ; expected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to do a JS code in my websitem but it returns me an error
Code:

```
 var f1 = document.getElementById("<%UserName.ClientID ;%>").value;
    var f2 = document.getElementById("<%email.ClientID ;%>").value;
    var f3;
    f3 = document.getElementById("<%Password.ClientID ;%>").value;
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: why the semi colon? e.ClientID ;

Comment: compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected


Source File: c:\Users\Gal\Desktop\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Register.aspx    Line: 9 

f3 = document.getElementById("<%Password.ClientID %>").value;

Answer (score 2):

should be `<%=UserName.ClientID%>` or `<%:UserName.ClientID%>` if you are using asp.net mvc

Answer (score 2):

Use `<%=` instead.

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("<%=UserName.ClientID%>").value;
```

Comment: grrr... i hate when people do that and don't explain themselves. Upvoted to offset the unnecessary downvote..

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `;` in your code. and missing the `=`

change

`<%UserName.ClientID ;%>  <%email.ClientID ;%> <%Password.ClientID ;%>`

To

`<%= UserName.ClientID %> <%= email.ClientID %> <%= Password.ClientID %>`

Alternatively, if you're using .Net 4 or above you can set the `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your controls and you don't need to call `.ClientID`.

So for example, a textbox would be:

`<asp:Textbox runat="Server" ID="email" ClientIDMode="Static" />`

You just use the ID of the element, I.E

`var f2 = document.getElementById("email").value;`

This makes life and code SO much cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("<%= UserName.ClientID %>").value;
var f2 = document.getElementById("<%= email.ClientID %>").value;
var f3;
f3 = document.getElementById("<%= Password.ClientID %>").value;
```

I changed "<%" to "<%=" and removed the semicolon at the end.

e.g. From <%UserName.ClientID ;%>  to <%= UserName.ClientID %>